# `campaign` and `customer` can be segmented by `convertion_action` but not natively get fields of `convertion_action`?

Tags: google-ads-api

How can it be that `convertion_action` G-Ads report table can natively get fields of `customer` but not the other way around.

Also: `campaign` and `customer` can be segmented by `convertion_action` but not natively get fields of `convertion_action`?

[image]

[image]

[image]